# Check a property is not null in search rest api

Tags: rest, query, people-search

I write this query for search user in a site.

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&sourceid='b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31'
```

I want to add a filter that the result must contains WorkEmail. I have tried `not(WorkEmail:null)` in `querytext` as well as `refinementfilters`, these does not work. How can i do this?

Comment: ``refinementfilters:'WorkEmail:not(ends-with(.com))'``  see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff394606.aspx#fql_endswith_operator

Answer (score 0):

Based on this article [here](https://www.itunity.com/article/filter-empty-values-search-693) (which I have used several times in my own environment), you could do something like the following for querytext:

`WorkEmail:a* OR WorkEmail:b* OR WorkEmail:c* OR WorkEmail:d* OR WorkEmail:e* OR WorkEmail:f* OR WorkEmail:g* OR WorkEmail:h* OR WorkEmail:i* OR WorkEmail:j* OR WorkEmail:k* OR WorkEmail:l* OR WorkEmail:m* OR WorkEmail:n* OR WorkEmail:o* OR WorkEmail:p* OR WorkEmail:q* OR WorkEmail:r* OR WorkEmail:s* OR WorkEmail:t* OR WorkEmail:u* OR WorkEmail:v* OR WorkEmail:w* OR WorkEmail:x* OR WorkEmail:y* OR WorkEmail:z* OR WorkEmail:1* OR WorkEmail:2* OR WorkEmail:3* OR WorkEmail:4* OR WorkEmail:5* OR WorkEmail:6* OR WorkEmail:7* OR Customer:8* OR Customer:9* OR Customer:0*`

Like the aritcle states, this is not very user friendly, but it would work well with the Search REST API for you